# SOAP, JSON and POX in same restful wcf

Tags: wcf, json, rest, soap

I am trying to have SOAP and RESTful in the same WCF service. I have ahieved it as well apart from one issue. Following is my web.config:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" name="MyServices">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
         name="basicHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttp"
          name="wsHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttp" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
          name="webHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttp" behaviorConfiguration="webJSONBehavior"
          name="webJSONHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.ISharedServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"    contract="IMetadataExchange"   name="mexBinding" />        
       </service>    
    </services>
```

When I have all the endpoints it gives the following error:

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CreateWsdlBindingAndPort(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, Port& wsdlPort, Boolean& newBinding, Boolean& bindingNameWasUniquified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Things work fine if I comment out json end point.

Can you please help me finding out why??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

well I just added changed the binding configuration for json behaviour. I was using same binging configuration for JSON and POX. Now I have changed the configuration to:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviour" name="MyServices">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
         name="basicHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttp"
          name="wsHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttp" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
          name="webHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebjsonHttp" behaviorConfiguration="webJSONBehavior"
          name="webJSONHttpBinding" contract="DJSharedServices.IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"    contract="IMetadataExchange"   name="mexBinding" />        
       </service>
```

and added binding configuration:

```
 <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttp"  >
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="WebjsonHttp"  >
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Any idea why the two endpoints can't share a binding for the wsdl to work?

Comment: @Jayrdub I think because it needs different address, and different address needs different proxies.

Comment: yea and there's no out of the box functionality with WCF like there is with the WebAPI where it'll allow you to keep your URLs cleaner by taking out the address="json", address="xml" yada yada.  WebApi looks at your content-type and figures that out on its own which is a nice time saver in code across your services and config.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favour and stop trying to create one service that does both SOAP and REST.  You are going to end up with a mess.  Review your requirements and pick the approach this is most suitable to your needs.

Comment: why do you say that?? Do you have some links which says that this approach is not suitable,, or any other other approach is better?

Comment: @Priya10 SOAP is a protocol that supports the implementation of a remote object architecture.  REST is completely different architectural style.  Either is a valid approach, for the right scenario, but the two are not compatible.

Comment: @DarrelMiller : that's not going to fly when one customer wants REST and the other wants SOAP interfaces into essentially the same functionality

Comment: @Sid  So create two distinct services that expose your application.  If you do them right, they won't look anything like each other, unless of course your application is pure CRUD.

Comment: I think there is no need for a second service, he could create a second interface with the same method definitions but different configuration attributes about REST operations. The service implementation could be the same implementing both interfaces.

Comment: @taskosgeorge Creating an "interface" to expose a REST service is completely defeating the point of REST.  REST services are intended to allow the server interface to evolve without updating the client by coupling on the contents of the message, not on the available resources.